# How to send signals from a backgrounded process using pexpect

Tags: python, linux, bash, signals, pexpect

Using python3/linux/bash:

```
gnr@localhost: cat my_script
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time, pexpect

p = pexpect.spawn('sleep 123')
p.sendintr()
time.sleep(1000)
```

This works fine when run as is (i.e. `my_script` starts a `sleep 123` child process and then sends it a `SIGINT` which kills `sleep 123`). However, when I background `my_script` as a grandchild process, it no longer is able to kill the `sleep 123` command:

```
gnr@localhost: (my_script &> /dev/null &)
```

Anyone know what's going on here/how to change `my_script` or `pexpect` to be able to still send `SIGINT` to it's child process?

I'm thinking this is has something to do with the backgrounding causing there to be no controlling terminal, and maybe I need to create a new pty?

Update: Never figured out how to create a pty (though ssh'ing into localhost with a -t option worked) - ended up doing an os.fork() to background a child process rather than the `(my_script &> /dev/null &)` which works because (I'm guessing) the controlling terminal is not immediately closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the process isn't being killed? I would expect it to show `<defunct>` in the process list as the process that spawned is now sitting in a `sleep` and proper cleanup can't complete until `sleep` finishes. `<defunct>` processes have been killed, just their parents haven't done the cleanup.

If you can somehow modify your code so that the parent actually goes through the normal processing and shuts down the child (spawn) then it should work. Although clumsy this might work:

```
import time, pexpect, os

newpid = os.fork()
if newpid == 0:
    # Child
    p = pexpect.spawn('sleep 123')
    p.sendintr()
else:
    # parent
    time.sleep(1000)
```

In this case we `fork` our own child who handles the spawn and does the kill. Since our child isn't blocking on its own `sleep` it exits gracefully which includes properly cleaning up the process it killed. In the mean time the main (parent) thread is waiting on a `sleep`

After your comment it occurred to me that although I was placing my script in the background at the bash prompt, I wasn't doing it the same as yours.

I was using

```
(expecttest.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
```

This redirects stdin and stdout to >/dev/null and puts the process in the background.

If I take your original code and rather than doing a `sendintr` and instead do a `terminate` using your invocation from the command shell it works. It seems that `sleep 123` doesn't respond to what pexpect is doing in that case.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure that it's still alive - I tried running your code, but I just end up with 2 `my_script` processes and a single `sleep 123` process - again this is if I run `my_script` as `(my_script &> /dev/null &)`

Comment: i think this is on the right track though, i've been trying with `pty.fork()` and `pty.openpty()` though haven't figured it out

Comment: I amended my answer. When running my script I put it in the background slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately I can't use terminate() either - the real program that's being run instead of `sleep 123` has a different user (through a bit of sudo magic) and so sending it `SIGTERM` is not an option.

Comment: Ah okay that detail then changes everything.